# error when I try to debug CodeAnalysisTest Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I downloaded Roslyn compile from GitHub. I am using VS 2015 enterprise and then I install xunit **(xunit.runner.console.2.0.0)** and when I launch command for test or debug I got error

**System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version = 42.42.42.42, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 31bf3856ad364e35**"

Can anyone help me with this?  Thanks.